# ¿Cuál es la librería que me calcule el tiempo de ejecución al momento de importar librería de Python?

Tags: python

tengo este código de importar las librerías

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from nltk import word_tokenize
import string
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este codigo puede que te sirva

```
from time import time

start_nb = time()

start = time()
```